# Laravel 5.8 Help on creating a save feature

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently building a recipe application in Laravel where you can create your own user profile, upload recipes, and follow other people to see what they upload. I am trying to build a feature where you can save other people recipes that you liked. Since I'm a neewbie, I am having trouble knowing where to start. I don't need anyone to type out a fully functioning feature, I'm just looking for some help from someone to point me in the right direction. Would really appreciate the help!

Once again I want a user to be able to save a recipe that has been uploaded by other users. Please let me know if you need more detailed information in order to help. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry sir, but this is not a correct platform to asking this question.

Comment: All the information you need is given in Laravel's documentation itself.
here's the link, https://laravel.com/docs/5.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel models have a [replicate](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_replicate) function that "clones the model into a new, non-existing instance.".

```
$new_recipe_model = $existing_recipe_model->replicate();
$new_recipe_model->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$new_recipe_model->save();
```

This is just an example ofcourse, if you have any further questions about this feel free to ask.

Comment: So, if I have a table in my database called "saved_recipes", and it has two columns called 'user_id' and 'recipe_id' which are both foreign keys on the users and recipes table, respectively. Will I be able to access all posts that a particular user has saved? I have a oneToMany relationship between my User and Recipe model.

Comment: You mean you want to replicate all recipes from a certain user? I don't think Laravel can do that for you so you'd probably have to loop through the relationship and replicate each one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Make the save button on the recipe a form, that takes both the logged in users' id, and the recipe id.

When the save button is clicked, send this information to a database table, and connect the recipe to the user using eloquent using the "hasmany()" function.

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: Much appreciated, this helps a lot too! Thank you! :)